# PulseAudio streaming randomly stops working then works

Tags: linux-mint, pulseaudio, bluetooth, usb-audio

I am streaming audio stereo input from a USB Behringer U-Control UCA202 to a Bluetooth attached wireless headphone. The audio stream stops randomly every seconds to minutes and lasting for seconds up to a half minute or more.

The system is running Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3.
The UCA202 is Device-2:

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:02c8 
           Device-2: Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec type: USB 
           driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus ID: 1-3:36 chip ID: 08bb:2902
```

I don't know much about PulseAudio streaming but was able to get it to work with a pacmd command that created a loopback of the PCM2902 Audio Codec showing up in the Playback section of the PulseAudio Volume Control app.

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=5
```

Perhaps the stalling is an audio related process being swapped out or related to the latency setting. I'm just guessing and don't know what to do or how to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Does this only happen with your bluetooth output device, or also with other audio outputs?

Comment: mashuptwice, it's my lan server so this is the only audio application on it; so don't know.

Comment: I tried lock-memory=yes in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf but pulseaudio at reboot fails to load, and can't find any error message in syslog that is related.